# Is this possible to search a encrypted data?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, security

net framework to do encrypted the data, and store in the database. But I would like to query the encrypted data, except from decryption the data one by one. Is this possible to query the encrypted data? Thanks.

P.S. I use the `Framework.Security.TripleDES` class for encryption, and using MSSQL database. Thanks.

Comment: If it were that easy, why bother encrypt?  If i wanted your data i could skip the encryption crap and just grab the data right out of the DB instead.

Comment: not unless you know the encryption params. thats the whole point of encryption...

Comment: how do you store your encryped data in base ?

Comment: @naveen: The *database* would have to have the encryption params, if it's ever going to be able to query the data.  And if i can get to your database, and it can easily query that data, i don't care whether it's encrypted -- cause the database will decrypt it for me.  :P

Comment: @cHao: if thats the case, he won't be asking this question, right? :P oops.. i was not replying to your comment... i was commenting on the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition **NO**. If your encrypted data is searchable, the encryption is broken. You must use a different, random, IV for each item encrypted and the only way to search is to decrypt every item and compare it with the searched item. Which is prohibitive. What you can do is store also a hash of the data and search the hash, see [Indexing Encrypted Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2006/03/11/549754.aspx). This allows you to quickly do extact searched, but no partial searched nor range searches.

Comment: Partial searches can be done, but this involves using multiple hashes such as "4 character hash", "6 character hash", "full hash" as an example. It adds to the amount of data you need to store, and may introduce security issues if done incorrectly (See PBKDF2, and properly salting your hashes). Using an encoding scheme for the column names can help automate a generic way of using this in your database.

Comment: @MichaelBrown: if you salt the hash then you cannot use it to search. If you don't salt them, then the entire hash function space of '4 characters' is easily discoverable and you leak information.

Comment: By salting the hash, I meant a table-wide salt not a row-level salt. Yes, exposing the first 4 characters would potentially leak data with this method, but it would only leak the first 4 characters through a rainbow-table type attack. It depends on your data as to if this is acceptable or not, and there are no other ways to enable searching of this kind. Using high iterations on PBKDF2 will make brute forcing the full-size hashes nearly impossible.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the same IV to encrypt each record, you can do simple searches by encrypting the searched string and comparing with stored data. However, if you need more complicated searches, you are out of luck unless you reconsider the architecture of your application.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot!

Ecryption is used to make meaningfull data meaningless (for other people). So no one can intercept your private data.

I guess your encrypted data is stored in a byte-array. Every byte is result of encryption and therefor pretty meaningless (except for the excryption mechanism). If data was meaningfull, than the ecryption is of a very poor quality.

Of course you can search your byte array for certain bytes. Of course you can count all the zero's, but I do not see the point.